# Cannot resolve method 'LoadAd' in 'View'

Tags: android, picasso

So I am new to android programming. I'm trying to learn it so that I can work on my college project which is online food ordering application. So as being a newbie, I am refering to this video tutorials-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ad41Bh704ms&list=PLaoF-xhnnrRW4lXuIhNLhgVuYkIlF852V

The uploader is using android studio version 2.3.3,while I am using android studio 3.3.1 . So I am aware that there are few changes here and there. Right now, I am stuck at one such change from that version of picasso....

I have used the exact code group as him, but to me,it gives error at "load"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z8Gc.png)

This is what it says-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0qLl.png)

I have added this version of picasso as dependency in my build.gradle..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDS2L.png)
Can anyone help me out here please? What could be triggering error in 'load',and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: `getBaseContext()` returns `Context`, which for sure does not have `load()` method. Your braces are wrong

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) - instead, you should include a [mcve] **as text**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a typo. Instead of writing

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext().load(food.getImage())).into(food_image);
```

use

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage()).into(food_image);
```

Comment: well, happens to the best of us.

Comment: I too sometimes get stuck at such situations and after a search of hours, find the silliest mistake in programming ;(

Comment: For simple typos, it's probably better to comment and vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

You did a typing mistake over there. A method that is started must be closed. What you typed:

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext().load(food.getImage())).into(food_image);
```

What is should be:

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage()).into(food_image);
                             ^
```

Check that you started the `with()` method and didn't close it.

Comment: Yea, realised it now..Thanks for helping bro

Comment: No problem Dude